# How to prevent access to some kind of files in server from client browser using httpd.conf

Tags: apache

I 'm having files with kind of extension :sample .txt,.js,.html and extensions specified by self. I want to deny the access to those files on my Apache web server. Deny access means, now i m able to access those file when i put the file name along with URL on browser and file is being displayed on browser.i don't want to show it on browser.

Dear Down Voters, Humble request, Question may have clarification issue, Whenever you do please comment with the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below in httpd.conf

```
<FilesMatch "\.js">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

According to File Extensions change above js,txt etc. This helped.